# Is there a way to add a tittle to multiple columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame like this [Head of df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPLsw.png)

I want to have a title with name "Cumulative mean" above the second,third and fourth column, in order to avoid writing this 3 times in every column.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Firstly, avoid having same column names in a dataframe.

Comment: Also, please share a sample of the dataframe, not an image

Comment: this is my dataframe,  it consists from 4 lists.                          
ListsForDataframe = [errors,listforcummulativesumperDay,listforcummulativesumperHour,listforcummulativesumperMinute]
df_cummulative_temp = pd.DataFrame(ListsForDataframe)
df_cummulative=df_cummulative_temp.T
df_cummulative = df_cummulative.rename(columns={0: 'ERRORS', 1: 'Cumulative mean(days)',2: 'Cumulative mean(Hour)',3: 'Cumulative mean(Minute)'})
df_cummulative

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: I think you just want `DataFrame.add_prefix`

Comment: rename the columns: `DataFrame.columns = ['ERRORS', 'Cumulative Mean(Days)', 'Cumulative Mean(Hour)', 'Cumulative Mean(Minute)']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Pandas MultiIndex: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

E.g., (example is simply adapted from docs)

```
col_names = [['', 'Cumulative mean', 'Cumulative mean', 'Cumulative mean'],['error', 'days', 'hour', 'minute']]
col_tuples = list(zip(*col_names))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(col_tuples)

# use random numbers
listsForDataframe = np.array([
    np.random.normal(size=4), #list1
    np.random.normal(size=4), #list2
    np.random.normal(size=4), #list3
    np.random.normal(size=4)  #list4
])

# create the dataframe from lists like you did from the comment
# include the multiindex object
pd.DataFrame(listsForDataframe.T,columns=index)
```

Result:

```
            Cumulative mean                    
      error            days      hour    minute
0  0.008628        0.037006 -0.805627 -1.951804
1  0.527004        0.767902 -1.118312 -0.659892
2  0.453782        0.589880 -0.131054 -1.139802
3 -1.829740       -0.363859  1.133080  0.784958
```

Subsetting by the 'Cumulative mean' multi-column then gives `print(d[['Cumulative mean']])`:

```
  Cumulative mean                    
             days      hour    minute
0        0.037006 -0.805627 -1.951804
1        0.767902 -1.118312 -0.659892
2        0.589880 -0.131054 -1.139802
3       -0.363859  1.133080  0.784958
```

Answer (score 1):

I got what you mean, posting a dummy situation:

Consider the below dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],columns=['a','cum_a','cum_b'])
print(df)
   a  cum_a  cum_b
0  1      2      3
1  4      5      6
2  7      8      9
```

We target to change columns with a pattern, example `cum_a`, `cum_b`. This can be done by using `df.filter()`:

```
values_to_rename=['change1','change2'] #sequential list of values to replace
d=dict(zip(df.filter(like='cum').columns,values_to_rename)) #create a dict
#{'cum_a': 'change1', 'cum_b': 'change2'}
```

---

```
df=df.rename(columns=d)
print(df)

   a  change1  change2
0  1        2        3
1  4        5        6
2  7        8        9
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this if you can

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df[[ 'column_new_1', 'column_new_2','column_new_3']] = [np.nan, 'dogs',3]
```

This could possibly solve the issue

or you can try using this sample

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7]
 })
```

These are samples that you can use but of course you will need to add the data yourself.

Hope this helps to create multiple line of columns